# VSTest branch coverage missing on fixed statement

Tags: c#, code-coverage, vstest

I'm running VSTest with code coverage enabled, output cobertura, and visualize it in Azure DevOps. It suggests I'm missing branch coverage on a fixed statement. What branches are there even to consider for a fixed statement?

Tooltip says "Partially covered (1 visits, 2 of 4 branches covered)".

[image]